# How to load multiple regex patterns from a file and match a given string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, regex-negation

Based on the code supplied (simplified for this post), can someone help show how I can get a list (if 'list' is the correct type to use) of regex patterns to load from a text file and be matched to a single string?

There are many examples of loading text/text strings from a file and matching to a regex pattern but not the other way around - many regex patterns to one text string.

As you'll probably see in the code if I manually create a list and run re.compile I can use the list of patterns to match to the string.  However where does the re.compile fit in when loading from a file?

```
import regex as re

fname = 'regex_strings_short.txt'

string_to_match = 'onload=alert'

# Create a manual list of regexes
manual_regexes = [
    re.compile(r'(?i)\bHP\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b'),
    re.compile(r'(?i)\bgmail\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b'),
    re.compile(r'(?i)\bearthlink\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b '),
    re.compile(r'(?i)onload=alert')
]

# Create a text file with these five example patterns
'''
(?i)\bHP\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b
(?i)\bgmail\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b
(?i)\bearthlink\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b
(?i)onload=alert
(?i)hello
'''

# Import a list of regex patterns from the created file
with open(fname, 'r') as file:
    imported_regexes = file.readlines()

# Notice the difference in the formatting of the manual list with 'regex.Regex' and 'flags=regex.I | regex.V0' wrapping each item
print(manual_regexes)
print('---')
print(imported_regexes)

# A match is found in the manual list, but no match found in the imported list
if re.match(imported_regexes[3], my_string):
    print('Match found in imported_regexes.')
else:
    print('No match in imported_regexes.')

print('---')

if re.match(manual_regexes[3], my_string):
    print('Match found in manual_regexes.')
else:
    print('No match in manual_regexes.')
```

There is no match for imported_regexes but there is for manual_regexes.

UPDATE:  The code below is the final solution that worked for me.  Posting it as it may help someone landing here and needing a solution.

```
# You must use regex as re and not just 'import re' as \p{} is not correctly escaped

import regex as re



# Add the post/string to match below

my_string = '<p>HP Support number</p>'



fname = 'regex_strings.txt'



# Contents of text file similar to the below

# but without the leading # space - that's only because it's an inline comment here

# (?i)\bHP\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b

# (?i)\bgmail\b(?:[^.,;]{1,20}?)\bnumber\b

# (?i)】\b(?:[^.,;]{1,1000}?)\p{Lo}



# Import a list of regex patterns from a file

with open(fname, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:

    loaded_patterns = f.read().splitlines()



# print(loaded_patterns)

print(len(loaded_patterns))



found = 0

for index, pattern in enumerate (loaded_patterns):

    if re.findall(loaded_patterns[index],my_string):

        print('Match found. ' + loaded_patterns[index])

        found = 1



if found == 0:

    print('No matching regex found.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` accepts strings as well as compiled regex as arguments, and converts strings internally into compiled regex objects. You can call `re.compile` for optimization purpose (several times calling the same regex) but this is purely optional for program correctness.

If the program does not prints the imported regex are matching, it's because `readlines()` keeps trailing `'\n'` in your strings. Thus `re.match('(?i)onload=alert\n')` returns `False` with the string to match. You can call re.compile, or not, on the sanitized strings.

```py
with open(fname, 'r') as file:
    imported_regexes = file.readlines()
print(re.match(imported_regexes[3].strip('\n'), string_to_match))
```

Outputs a matchobject.